# Is there a way making python produce the same result bit-wise shift left with java?

Tags: java, python, bit

I have to transfer some function from java code to Python.
but the  bit shift left return different result.
And Python lack of the >>> operator in java

how to make them same? 
Python :  6116937115306182825 << 11  = 12527487212147062425600

java :    6116937115306182825 << 11  = 2147986098276878336

Answer (score 6):

java has a limited number of bits(64) whereas python doesn't ... so you need to force it to the right number of bits(64)

```
(6116937115306182825 << 11) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

Comment: Not true, you can [use BigInteger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59188831/5221149).

Comment: sure but he wasnt asking how to get java to give him the same answer as python ... he was asking how to get python to give him the same answer as java

Answer (score 2):

When you need integer values that exceeds the size of `long`, i.e. values larger than 9_223_372_036_854_775_807, use `BigInteger`:

```
System.out.println(new BigInteger("6116937115306182825").shiftLeft(11));
```

*Output*

```
12527487212147062425600
```